# Add plugin to ejs?

Tags: templates, node.js, ejs

how i can add my own custom functions to ejs?

```
<%- custom_function('test') %>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your own filter to ejs.

```js
ejs.filters.custom_function = function(str) {
    return str + ' custom string';
};
```

In template you can access your filter like this:

```
<%=: 'somestring' | custom_function %>
```

You can pass additional parameters to your function using colon.

```js
ejs.filters.custom_function = function(str, postfix) {
    return str + postfix;
};
```

And In your template:

```
<%=: 'somestring' | custom_function:' custom postfix' %>
```